# Blazor is setting component parameter every time I interact with component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

What I want to achieve is to call a function every time Parameter value of a component is updated, So I created a component with a Parameter and call a method inside its setter like this.

```
private LookupConfig _lookupConfig;

Parameter]
public LookupConfig Config { get { return _lookupConfig; } set { _lookupConfig = value; Console.WriteLine("Parameter Setter"); InitializeDropdownValues(); } }
```

In my parent component, I have a property.

```
public LookupConfig CustomerDropdown = new LookupConfig { LookupType = LookupType.Customer };
```

and I am passing it to child component like this.

```
<NeeleezAutoComplete Config="CustomerDropdown"/>
```

but every time I interact with NeeleezAutoComplete component setter of Parameter property Config is get called.

is it intentional behaviour of blazor parameters am i missing something ? and how do i achieve this functionlaity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it intentional behaviour of blazor parameters

Yes, this is by design. Blazor tracks parameter changes very lightly.

The solution seems simple:

```
set 
{ 
  if (_lookupConfig == value) return;   // no change? Out of here. 
  _lookupConfig = value; 
  Console.WriteLine("Parameter Setter"); 
  InitializeDropdownValues(); 
}
```

You may want to check Equality for LookupConfig but normally the defaults should suffice.

Comment: I have done the same for now but in the method InitializeDropdownValues, but yes I can do it in setter too. Thank you for the help.

Comment: There are whole set of issues relating to using setters in component Parameters.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is fairly self explanatory.

```
<h3>MyDiv</h3>

@code {
    private bool veryBad;
    private bool bad;
    private bool good;

    [Parameter] public bool VeryBad
    {
        get => this.veryBad;
        set
        {
            this.veryBad = value;
            // Do lots of stuff
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public bool Bad
    {
        get => this.bad;
        set
        {
            this.bad = value;
            // Do something trivial
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public bool Good { get; set; }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        if (!this.good.Equals(this.Good))
        {
            // Do something 
        }
        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

The point is that any [Parameter] should look (exactly) like this:

```
[Parameter] public bool Good { get; set; }
```

If you want to do some checking, trigger some code if a specific value changes,....  do it in `SetParametersAsync` if you need to use it immediately, or in `OnParametersSet{async}` if you don't.

Set the parameters by calling `parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);` in the first line releases the Renderer to carry on it's job (when it gets thread time).  Note we call the base method with an empty `ParameterView` because we've already set them.

Adding code into setters means the setting code get run as part of `parameters.SetParameterProperties`, potentially slowing the whole `Renderer` process.

Comment: You haven't explained the _why_ here. And I would stay away from  SetParametersAsync, that really is a spooky method.   OnParametersSet{Async} is the best place to do this, maybe with some proper null handling.

Comment: @HenkHolterman.  NP in doing it in `OnParametersSet{Async}`.  Where you do it depends on what is affected.  I use `SetParametersAsync` because it's the first entry point to the component.  On why, I used to do it, but read some stuff by the Blazor team that said don't.  It's because any code in a setter gets run as part of the `Renderer` update process and potentially slows down the render process.  It's why you must use the `ParameterView` on the first line.   I just been searching but can't find the material - Enet probably can point us to it!